# highcharts / stock charts custom toolbar button text / title

Tags: highcharts

I would like to know how you can customise the tool tips for the custom buttons.

All the examples for custom buttons are like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/3496/) with `_titleKey: 'printButtonTitle'`

Setting this to anything else results in `undefined` as the tool tip. I have spent a while looking through the source for where this is created but cant find it.

Also though of using something like an id and replacing it with jquery `$('#foo-button title').html('yey');` but the custom buttons do not have ids assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an `id` to the button using `_id` and then update it using jQuery.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        'myButton': {
            _id: 'myButton',
            symbol: 'diamond',
            x: -62,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
            onclick: function() {
                alert('click!')
            }
        }
    }
}

var buttonTitle = 'updated title';
jQuery("#myButton").attr('title', buttonTitle).children().text(buttonTitle);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/8137/)

Comment: Thanks, strange you cant do something as simple as title: 'foobar' or tooltip: 'foobar'

Answer (score 6):

Although an answer is accepted, I would like to present an alternate solution.
Highcharts does give a way (unfortunately, not well documented though) to set custom titles for custom buttons. Highchart reads the strings from its global language object [`Highchart.lang`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#lang). To have a custom title, you will need to add the button title as a new property (you can call the new property by name, except the reserved ones) in this object using the `Highcharts.setOptions()` global method as follows

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        myButtonTitle: "Don't Click"
    }
});
```

One thing to keep in mind is this is a global property and hence is required to be set before making an constructor calls and you have to call it on the Highcharts namespace and not as a part of individual charting options.

You can now use the above set title in your buttons by specifying a `_titleKey` property for the button with the value corresponding to the key that was used above to set the name

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        'myButton': {
            _id: 'myButton',
            symbol: 'diamond',
            x: -62,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
            onclick: function() {
                alert('click!')
            },
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle"

        }
    }
}
```

[Custom Button Title | Highcharts & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hq93c/)